# How to sole htmlentities() error in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to display sum of some columns in laravel using query builder but getting this error:

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

This is the query:

```
$purchase = DB::table('purchases')
    ->join('currencies', 'currencies.cur_id', '=', 'purchases.currency_id')
    ->selectRaw('purchases.*, currencies.currency ,SUM(purchases.quantity*unit_price) as total, SUM(purchases.c_price*quantity) as usd_total')
    ->first();
```

And view:

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
      <p class="text-elg text-strong mb-0">
          {{ number_format($purchase->usd_total,2) }}
       </p>
           <span>Purchases</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**dd($purchase->usd_total)** an you will find the reason.

Comment: Result of dd($purchase->usd_total) is  "44,1290"

Comment: Have you check query? try to echo the query is it right or not

Comment: When I dd($purchase) it outputs this   {#111 ▼
  +"id": 1
  +"item_name": "Muscle"
  +"quantity": 12
  +"unit_price": "100.0000"
  +"c_price": "1.4440"
  +"description": ""
  +"buy_date": "2016-06-12"
  +"purchase_type_id": 1
  +"unit_id": 1
  +"currency_id": 2
  +"rate_id": 4
  +"brand_id": 1
  +"category_id": 1
  +"created_at": "2016-06-12 22:35:10"
  +"updated_at": "2016-06-12 22:35:10"
  +"currency": "AFN"
  +"total": "28900.0000"
  +"usd_total": "417.3280"
}